# Flask-limiter - How to find the key name that Flask-limiter stores in Redis

Tags: python, redis, rate-limiting, flask-limiter

I am rate limiting my application by user. I want to clear a key by a given user in redis.
How can I find how it is being stored in redis. There is a clear function in limits/storage that takes a key, but I don't know how the key is being stored in Redis

Comment: List your keys: https://redis.io/commands/KEYS

Comment: Flask-limiter stores it in keyspace, and not able to read the key in the key space

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

flask limiter sets the key as

```
LIMITER/127.0.0.1/slow/1/1/day
```

so use [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) - KEYS can end up taking out a production server

example when we are rate-limiting by IP address

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match *127.0.0.1*
1) "0"
2) 1) "LIMITER/127.0.0.1/slow/1/1/day"
```

Be aware that Rate-Limiter sets a [TTL](https://redis.io/commands/expire) on each key so it may be expired from the keyspace automatically and no longer be visible.